# parser error in API

Tags: ajax, api, bugzilla

I've been trying to connect to the buqzilla api to get the data related to my bug id. I'm getting a response code 200 and while debugging it is showing **parser error**. I've tried to replace the json formatted  values but of no use.

There is also another error regarding the **CORS**.

Can someone please help with this.Thanks in Advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function Call() {

      var requiredParameters = [{
        "Bugzilla_login": "@@email@@",
        "Bugzilla_password": "@@pwd@@",
        "include_fields": "id"
      }];

      var connectionObject = {
        params: JSON.stringify(requiredParameters)

      };

      var bugId = 19301;
      var urlx = "http://engbugzilla:9898/" + "bug/" + bugId;
      alert("here");
      debugger;
      $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: urlx,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: "true",
        data: connectionObject,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("json");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(thrownError);
          console.log(thrownError);
        }

      });

    }

    Call();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [Bugzilla API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API), I have done some changes to your `urlx` variable and make this working.

Here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/me3yqnfr/10/).

Hope this is what you want!

Comment: The URL I've used is the server url where the bugzilla is hosted(local server).

Comment: Are you able to access the url from your local `http://engbugzilla:9898/bug/19301`. And what is output of that?

Comment: Content-Type text/html is not supported

Comment: That was the content displayed in my browser window when I accessed the URL

Comment: OK if you directly try to access this url in your browser the it's showing that message? `http://engbugzilla:9898/bug/19301`

Comment: Try to use latest jquery version and see if it working!

Comment: I've checked that but of no use...!

Comment: Actually I'm not able to access your local url so it's hard to find the exact issue? If you hosted that at a remote place that we can verify the issue!